# ¿Cómo hacer un delay en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Tengo un documento HTML, y dentro de este tengo unos botones, quiero que al pulsar un botón haga un delay y luego siga con el programa. Algo asi.

```
function subir-btn() // funcion creada en un botón en evento onclick
{

    // Hacer el delay 1 segundo
    document.getElementById("temperatura").innerText = "Caliente";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacer simplemente un [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("1 Segundo esperado")
}, 1000);
```

Esto hará que se espere una cantidad *x* de segundos antes de ejecutar algo, recibe como parámetros una función (Esta se ejecutará esperado el plazo) y el plazo en **milisegundos**, es decir que *1000* es *1s*

---

Además, si quieres hacer que algo se ejecute cada *x* tiempo, puedes usar [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Esto genera un intervalo en la ventana actual, se estará ejecutando algo constantemente

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Ejecutar cada 1 seg")
}, 1000);
```

Al igual que `setTimeout`, este recibe una función y la cantidad de tiempo en milisegundos.

Si deseas quitar el intervalo (anularlo) puedes usar `clearInterval()`

```javascript
window.clearInterval()
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias